# How can I specify the language of _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_?

Tags: php, report, amazon-mws

Recently I tried to get all Amazon listings from multiple marketplaces with `ReportType`: `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_`.

For MarketplaceIds

- `A1PA6795UKMFR9` (DE)
- `A1RKKUPIHCS9HS` (ES)
- `A1F83G8C2ARO7P` (UK)

the response columns were as the following:

```
item-name   item-description    listing-id  seller-sku  price   quantity
open-date   image-url   item-is-marketplace product-id-type zshop-shipping-fee
item-note   item-condition  zshop-category1 zshop-browse-path   zshop-storefront-   
feature asin1   asin2   asin3   will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping   
zshop-boldface  product-id  bid-for-featured-placement  add-delete  
pending-quantity    fulfillment-channel
```

English and(!) `asin1` is available. For marketplace `A13V1IB3VIYZZH` (FR) Amazon is responding with a different result:

```
nom-article réf-offre    sku-vendeur         prix       quantité    date-offre
type-réf-produit         remarque-article    état-article           livrable-monde  
livraison-eclair         réf-produit         quantité-en-attente    Canal de traitement
```

There is no `asinX`. Why? And how can I specify the language for the reports?

Comment: No, there's no way to specify a language for the report. Also, be aware that when you upload a feed it must be in the language that is applicable to that marketplace. See the section titled "Behavior of Feeds When Submitting Multiple Marketplace IDs" in the Feeds API reference http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/index.html

Comment: @JonathanSpooner I'm not sure if it matter, but i request only **one** report from **one** marketplace at the same time/request.

Comment: I'm trying to compile a list of all possible column header values here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274137/what-are-the-possible-amazon-mws-report-column-headers-after-last-localization

Maybe you can assist and benefit from my findings.

Comment: +1 Having the same problem. Do you know where I can find all possible translations of the report's header?

Answer (score 3):

Statement from Amazon after opening a case: "[...] I am sorry to inform you that the french active listing report has been set up differently to be more understable for most of the french sellers as most of them have difficulties to understand English language. [...]"

Answer (score 2):

we are experiencing the same problem with Amazons's API.

The _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ reports for DE, UK and IT are consistent but FR is completely different.

Also, we are getting some very strange IDs from the french report. Completely different to a standard ASIN (longer). The ID can be used to search the storefront and find the product with its correct ASIN, but doesn't work in seller central.

Comment: Look at my quote from amazon with one of the best reason for such useless behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17555426/1021809

Comment: we opened a ticket today.. lets see if they changed their mind in the meantime

Comment: Please report about the answer

Comment: Late follow-up: any updates on this issue? It got even worse with the translated headers.

Answer (score 1):

[MWS Announcement Post](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/amazon-mws-listings-reports-will-soon-be-available-in-your-default-local-language/343719)

From May 2014 onwards it is now possible to specify your preferred language for reports:

> To request that reports be translated into your default local
> language, log in to Seller Central and select Settings > Account Info
> > Feed Processing Report Language > Localized (report will be translated into default local language). After you enable this
> setting, both the headers and the contents of the reports will be
> translated. This option is available in all marketplaces except the
> United States and Canada.

Comment: For anyone arriving at this question, this is now the correct answer.