# What are the possible Amazon MWS Report column headers after last localization?

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm struggling with the following problem:

I want to import a merchants active listings from a `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` report, no drama so far.
But **depending on the merchants locale, the report column headers are different.**
In my quest to support all possible merchant locales, this is not acceptable.

I am pretty sure, there is no official resource, that specifies all possible header translations. If there is, I would be glad to learn about it.
My other hope is, that some fellow developers with access to merchants of one of the unknown regions can request a report and paste its **headers** here, so I can implement the handling in my software properly.

*Side Notes:

Other report types are affected, too.

The column ordering is also sometimes different (france), but that's not an issue.*

**My compiled list for `en / untranslated` and `de`**

Old headers, consistent for every merchant language:
`listing-id`
`item-name`
`seller-sku`
`asin1`
`item-description`

New german (`de`) headers:
`listing-id` = `Angebotsnummer`
`item-name` = `Artikelbezeichnung`
`seller-sku` = `Händler-SKU`
`asin1` = `Produkt-ID`
`item-description` = `Artikelbeschreibung`

New french (`fr`) headers:

`listing-id` = **unknown**
`item-name` = **unknown**
`seller-sku` = **unknown**
`asin1` = **unknown**
`item-description` = **unknown**

new italian (`it`) headers:

`listing-id` = **unknown**
`item-name` = **unknown**
`seller-sku` = **unknown**
`asin1` = **unknown**
`item-description` = **unknown**

new spanish (`es`) headers:

`listing-id` = **unknown**
`item-name` = **unknown**
`seller-sku` = **unknown**
`asin1` = **unknown**
`item-description` = **unknown**

Related SO question: [Amazon MWS: How to specify the language of _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272021/amazon-mws-how-to-specify-the-language-of-get-merchant-listings-data)
Related Amazon Announcment: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the translations of the `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` headers at the following link (this link is for DE marketplace):

https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_200385890_cont_561?ie=UTF8&itemID=200385890&language=de_DE

By changing the &language=de_DE to say, &language=fr_FR, you can get the French translations.  Same goes for Italian (it_IT), etc.

Comment: Not accurate. Please download and extract from report files.